# How can I "export" a model from Orange once I have prototyped a solution?

Tags: machine-learning-model, orange

Using Orange, I would like to use the underlying python model within the control system of my device.  A device is a simple machine that is not connected to the internet.  My intent is to use the model to the machine operating parameters based upon the application requirements.

Is there a way (or could there be) to export the trained model for use? This seems to be a missing feature or future enhancement for Orange.

Answer (score 0):

You can export any trained machine learning model in Orange using the **Save Model** widget.

This is what the `Save Model` widget does under the Model tab. Create your model, then click save model and your model will be saved to a [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pickle.html) file. Then just load your pickle file in Python.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598627/orange-save-model-in-python-script) is a similar question on Stack Overflow:

[image]